# update_user_meta as multiple value but with same meta key

Tags: php, functions, customization, loop

I have this code. When I save it, the user levels adding and gives time select input next to it. But when I give different time to levels, for example: Level 1: 2 weeks, Level 2: 9 Months

If saves only the last element, then all inputs display that value. How can I save different times? Where do I wrong?

```
//USER EDIT IN ADMIN DASHBOARD
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function crf_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    $user_levels = rua_get_user($user->ID)->get_level_ids();
    $elements = array();
    foreach ($user_levels as $user_level) {
        $present_date = date("Y-m-d");
        $end_time = get_the_author_meta( $user_level, $user->ID);
        $effectiveDate = strtotime($end_time, strtotime(date("Y-m-d")));
        $time = date("d/m/y", $effectiveDate);
        $elements[] = get_the_title($user_level) . 
        ' ->  <select name="' .$user_level. '" id="time-selector" style="width:180px;">
              <option value="default">Süre Seçiniz</option>
              <option value="+14 day" '.selected( $end_time, "+14 day"). '>2 Hafta</option>
              <option value="+9 months" '.selected( $end_time, "+9 months"). '>9 Ay</option>
              <option value="+12 months" ' .selected( $end_time, "+12 months"). '>12 Ay</option>
              <option value="+7 day" ' .selected( $end_time, "+7 day"). '>Uzat</option>
              </select>'  . $present_date . '   ' . $time .  '<br><br>';
    }
}


//SAVING DATE OF EACH LEVEL    
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'crf_update_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'crf_update_profile_fields' );

function crf_update_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    $user_levels = rua_get_user($user_id)->get_level_ids();
    foreach ($user_levels as $user_level) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $user_level, $_POST[ $user_level ] );
    }
}

//DELETING LEVEL
function my_demo_cronjob_action () {
    $present_date = date("Y-m-d");
    $user = get_user_by('id',26);
    $user_levels = rua_get_user($user)->get_level_ids(false, false, true);

    foreach ($user_levels as $level) {
      $end_time = get_the_author_meta( $level, $user->ID);
      $effectiveDate = strtotime($end_time, strtotime(date("Y-m-d")));
      $time = date("d/m/y", $effectiveDate);
      if ($present_date > $time) {
        rua_get_user($user)->remove_level($level);
      }
    }
}
add_action('my_demo_cronjob_action', 'my_demo_cronjob_action');
```

Comment: A side-note, you should use `get_user_meta` rather than `get_the_author_meta`

Comment: I did not understand. get_user_meta will solve it directly?

Comment: No, if it did I would have left an answer rather than a comment, you should still use `get_user_meta` instead, `get_the_author_meta` is innapropriate for this use case

Comment: my problem is, how can I store the meta as multiple

Comment: I know, as I said it was a comment, not an answer. Note that `get_user_meta` can do things that `get_the_author_meta` cannot. Technically `get_the_author_meta` shouldn't work here as the field parameter should not be able t accept arbitrary meta  key values as there's a predefined whitelist, which means any answer will likely require `get_user_meta`, if not for that reason but because of its 3rd parameter. It is not possible to store the same meta key multiple times then retrieve them with `get_the_author_meta`, but it is with `get_user_meta`.

Comment: Also, the english in your question is very difficult to understand, are you asking how to change this to a checkbox list? What is the `$elements` array? It's unclear what your code is supposed to do. Please edit your question to make it easier to understand

Comment: sorry about that. my english is not advanced. just tell me How can I store multiple meta with same input name. there is a varible name $menu and this is a select menu, it gives access time. $menu varible is in foreach loop because of user levels. I have to give different access time for each levels. update_user_meta saving just last element of $elements array. $elements array gets user levels. there are 6 user levels

Comment: Where is this code located? What comes before and after it? Is this in a user edit screen in the Admin UI?

Comment: in functions.php the hook is `add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function crf_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {}`

Comment: and and saving hook is `add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'crf_update_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'crf_update_profile_fields' );

function crf_update_profile_fields( $user_id ) {}` and I have control function of it, So If present date greater than date of a level, the level will be remove but level's array removing all level.

Comment: can you edit your question to include that in the appropriate place, then include the level control code as well? I want to be able to reproduce this locally, I'm hoping I can replace the `rua_get_user` call with a hardcoded array and run tests

Comment: I wrote all functions

Comment: Is  `crf_show_extra_profile_fields` complete? I seethings being added to the `$elements` array but then nothing happens, it never gets used and nothing is output I also see a cron job callback, but no cron scheduling code. `crf_update_profile_fields` also has extra closing brackets that would cause a PHP fatal error

Comment: I added dates for level expiration but I have to write startdate too. the cronjob executing by a wordpress cron plugin. I did not understand what is the problem in update_fields?

Comment: The code adds HTML to an array named `$elements` but then it does nothing with that array, there is no `echo` statement, I don't see where it gets printed to the browser. Clearly there is something important missing. All the examples for `show_user_profile` have opening and closing PHP tags and output directly, I don't understand why there is an `$elements` array or how it gets printed, in that function it isn't printed, so there must be missing code. `crf_update_profile_fields` still has a PHP syntax error too, it has been modified to remove something

Comment: Fix the indenting in the `crf_update_profile_fields` function and it'll become obvious that there are 2 opening `{` brackets but 3 closing brackets `}`, the code in your question should generate a PHP fatal error, and it would not add any fields to the user profile page. It is clearly incomplete and broken. I've fixed the indenting on that function so the bug should now be super obvious. I understand that you have unrelated code you are trying to hide, but doing so is not helpful, it's unproductive

Comment: Also, those user levels, what do the values look like? Are they just numbers?

Comment: the brackets are my mistake I fixed it. Also I put your codes and it works except get_user_meta. but now I have a new problem. the problem is start_time. because when I give end_time, it always updating because of date(). So I have to give a start date when press "update user info" button. How can I do this?

Comment: You'll have to ask a new question for that, but I'd also spend some time rewording it as that new question is very difficult to parse in english

Comment: anyway, thanks for your help and interested for a week. I accepted your answer. I appreciate you :)

Comment: hi there again. I have a new problem again. it is "delete an array element when its date expires" https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/379130/delete-a-specific-array-element-when-date-expired-of-it can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML select tags for each level all have the same name and ID, and will overwrite each other. They ***must*** be unique. **You will need separate names, IDs, and meta for each user level input.**

Likewise, the user meta keys need to be unique. The code also needs to use `get_user_meta` instead ( `get_the_author_meta` is only to be used inside a post loop ).

I suggest using something similar to this:

```php
    foreach ($user_levels as $user_level) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'time-selector-' . $user_level, $_POST[ 'time-selector' . $user_level ] );
    }
```

Then changing your input names and IDs accordingly. e.g. `<select name='time-selector-' . $user_level . '`You will also need to adjust your `get_user_meta` call to use the new keys

There is another mistake in your code however. `selected` does not return a string, it outputs it, so the `selected="selected"` HTML will be output in the wrong place. You need to pass a  3rd parameter `false` to make it return, otherwise your HTML markup will be incorrect, and the selected attribute will be displayed before the input markup is displayed.

Here is an example:

Saving the meta:

```php
$rua_user = rua_get_user( $user->ID );
$user_levels = $rua_user->get_level_ids();

// save existing values if they exist
foreach ( $user_levels as $level ) {
    $metakey = 'time-selector-' . $level;
    if ( isset( $_POST[ $metakey ] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $metakey, $_POST[ $metakey ] );
    }
}
```

Displaying the input:

```php
$choices = [
    'two'  => 'Two Weeks',
    'nine' => '9 months',
];

$rua_user = rua_get_user( $user->ID );
$user_levels = $rua_user->get_level_ids();

foreach ( $user_levels as $level ) {
    $metakey = 'time-selector-' . $level;
    $time    = get_user_meta( $user->ID, $metakey, true );
    ob_start();
    echo esc_html( get_the_title( $level ) ) . ' -> ';
    ?>
    <select
        name='time-selector-<?php echo esc_attr( $level ); ?>'
        id='time-selector-<?php echo esc_attr( $level ); ?>'
        style='width:180px;'
    >
        <option value='default'>Select time</option>
        <?php
        foreach ( $choices as $value => $label ) {
            ?>
            <option
                value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>"
                <?php selected( $value, $time ); ?>
            >
                <?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?>
            </option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $elements[] = $html;
}
// ... etc
```

Note several important things:

- All levels have unique and independent HTML markup, and post meta
- Nothing is shared between each field, if things were shared they would not be separate
- I used an output buffer to make the HTML easier to read and generate
- I added escaping, an important security feature
- The list of times is no longer hardcoded, and was moved to a separate array to simplify the code and reduce repetition. This also means they can be filtered, added to, etc
- The save code is in a separate snippet, handling post/user save should not happen on the same hook as displaying the data.

  - By putting the save code inside the display code in your original question, you may have introduced a bug
- Because the user meta keys have changed, all prior data will need to be re-saved. This should not be an issue as the prior data is broken due to the way your original code worked. Any data loss that could occurred already happened before you wrote the question.
- If you try to use this snippet, you will not see the full list of times. I deliberately limited the array to 2 entries to prevent people using this as a copy paste solution. Anybody with beginner level PHP skills can update the array to add the other choices

Comment: my select menu is not multiple. it has not to be multiple. $menu variable will next to each level. let me show you with some pictures. Also get_user_meta not working.

https://imgur.com/GQ25QrA - 
https://imgur.com/q2O4XUR

maybe I could explain with pictures.

Comment: @freedom667 please edit your question to include that information, it significantly changes the meaning of your question

Comment: nothing changed, also get_user_meta returns null

Comment: @freedom667 I can't see the code changes you've made to use `get_user_meta` so I don't know how to help or what went wrong. TLDR all your inputs have the same name, and you only store the value once. If you have 5 user levels, then you need 5 inputs, 5 input names, 5 IDs, 5 meta keys, not 1

Comment: but the levels can be 4,3 or 1. So, the levels are not fixed. one user has 5 levels, another user has 2 levels. it works this way.

Comment: I saw, you already have a list of the levels in an array named `$user_levels`, just use a loop. The names, user meta key, and IDs must be unique, there is no getting around that, it is a hard requirement and unavoidable. They must be unique, they cannot be the same, you cannot create the HTML for the `select` once then reuse it for every single user level because then they all have the same HTML/names/IDs, it has to be done inside the loop

Comment: the I should assign a variable to input name and it will give different name in loop, right? for example '<input name="'. $user_level ."'>, right?

Comment: correct, in my answer I name it `<select name='time-selector-' . $user_level . '....`

Comment: but then, I cannot put $menu variable because input should be in foreach. input names will be level ids. $user_level collecting level ids

Comment: Your use of the `$menu` variable outside the loop does not work, you should not use a `$menu` variable, it is causing problems. Each select ***must*** be unique, they cannot be the same, they have to be different. There is no avoiding this

Comment: I already understood, my question is, the html tags will be in loop?

Comment: I thought I did it. but as I said, just get_the_author_meta works. I don't know why. I wrote echo for control, because I wondered the output. gives me like this. `two selected='selected'twelve selected='selected'nine selected='selected'two selected='selected'twelve selected='selected'nine selected='selected' ` the first text is two, this is last element but why is there I don't know

Comment: Yes, otherwise the HTML tag would be the same for all select inputs, likewise it looks like you haven't spotted my comment on using the `selected` function, check the third parameter. To be able to help you debug the new code I'll need to be able to see it

Comment: Fundamentally, these are all separate fields, that need separate HTML, separate handling, separate saving. You cannot share things to save time, they need to be treated as unique individual fields. I'm including a limited example in my answer shortly

Comment: I will try your code. if it works, I will accept your answer

Comment: @freedom667 I hadn't tested it out, but it's about 99% there, I just spotted a silly typo I made and updated it

Comment: did not work. I saved but gives me null

Comment: @freedom667 quick question, your code example in your original question, how is it being executed? It's missing the context such as what hook it runs on, what happens to the `$elements` array, etc. Also how are you testing that it's `null`?

Comment: gives me null because all select input output is default again after saved.

Comment: So you haven't checked the actual value? That does not mean the value is `null`, it could mean the `selected` part is incorrect. I asked in my last comment several important questions about how the code is executed and where it's located but you did not answer any of those questions. Can you answer them? It is super important. What does the rest of the code in your question look like? How is it being ran?