# delete an array element when its date expires

Tags: php, functions, customization, loop

I have user levels for access content. I made a start date and end date input for each other. Each level has its own history. Whichever level date exceeds today's date, it will be removed from user levels array, but all of them are removed in my function. How can I do that?

This function is just adds levels with end dates.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function crf_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
  $choices = [
    '+15 minutes'  => '2 Hafta',
    '+9 months' => '9 Ay',
    '+12 months' => '12 Ay',
    '+2 minutes' => 'Uzat',
];
$rua_user = rua_get_user( $user->ID );
$user_levels = $rua_user->get_level_ids();
$current_date = date("d/m/y H:i:s");

  foreach ( $user_levels as $user_level ) {

    $start_time_meta = 'start-time-'.$user_level;
    $start_time = get_the_author_meta( $start_time_meta, $user->ID);

    $end_time_meta = 'end-time-'.$user_level;
    $end_time = get_the_author_meta( $end_time_meta, $user->ID);

    $effectiveDate = strtotime($end_time, strtotime($start_time));
    $time = date("d/m/y H:i:s", $effectiveDate);

    ob_start();

    echo esc_html( get_the_title( $user_level ) ) . ' -> ';
    ?>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="start-time-<?php echo esc_attr( $user_level ); ?>" name="start-time-<?php echo esc_attr( $user_level ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $start_time ); ?>"> - 

    <select name='end-time-<?php echo esc_attr( $user_level ); ?>' id='end-time-<?php echo esc_attr( $user_level ); ?>' style='width:180px;'>
        <option value='default'>Süre Seçiniz</option>
        <?php
        foreach ( $choices as $value => $label ) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>"
                <?php selected( $value, $end_time ); ?>>
                <?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?>
            </option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select> <?php echo $time; ?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $elements[] = $html;
  } ?>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Kitaplar', 'crf' ); ?></th>
            <td>
                <?php
                    sort($elements);
                    echo (vsprintf(__('%s'),implode("",$elements )));
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <?php
}
```

This function just delete the levels but I want to delete if a level's date is expires:

```php
    function my_demo_cronjob_action () {
        $present_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $user = get_user_by('id',26);
        $user_levels = rua_get_user($user)->get_level_ids(false, false, true);
    
        foreach ($user_levels as $level) {
    
            $end_time_meta = 'end-time-'.$level;
            $end_time = get_the_author_meta( $end_time_meta, $user);
    
            $effectiveDate = strtotime($end_time, strtotime($present_date));
            $time = date("d/m/y H:i:s", $effectiveDate);
    
            if ($present_date > $time) {
                rua_get_user($user)->remove_level($level);
            }
        }
    }
    add_action('my_demo_cronjob_action', 'my_demo_cronjob_action');
```

the cronjob function is executed by a cron plugin

Comment: why nobody helps me?

Comment: Have you contacted restrict user access support? 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here. Otherwise comparing 2 dates is not a WP problem, it's a generic PHP problem.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Tom J Nowell yes, I contacted him but nobody replied me

Comment: Actually, this is not about the plugin. this is about general question. I only asked remove array element if date expires. The plugin just delete it, that's all.